# align input in the middle

Tags: html, css

My input field for name and password won't align in the middle, can someone help me?
I've added the relevant HTML and CSS, hopefully you can figure out all the code :p.
....................................................................................

```
        <div class="login">
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="login_form">                      
                <div class="loginfield"><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
                <div class="loginfield"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" /></div>
                <input type="submit" id="loginbutton" name="loginbutton" value="Login" data-role=""  data-theme="" /> 
            </form>
            <p>Not a member? <a href="register.php">Sign up</a> now!</p>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.login input[type=password]{
    background: url(../images/password.png) 6px 4px no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7f7f8 0%,#ffffff 100%);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset, 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05) inset;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #222222;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 42px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 36px;
    width: 200px;
        @include breakpoint($tablet){
            width:300px;
            }
        @include breakpoint($desktopsmall){
            width:400px;
            }

    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       color: #999999;
    }

    &:-moz-placeholder {
       color: #999999;
    }

    &:focus{
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #2392F3 inset, 0 -1px 0 #2392F3 inset, 1px 0 0 #2392F3 inset, -1px 0 0 #2392F3 inset, 0 0 4px rgba(35,146,243,0.5);
        outline: none;
        background: url(../img/keyIcon.png) 12px 11px no-repeat, #FFF;
    }
}

.login input[type=text]{
    background: url(../images/user.png) 6px 4px no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7f7f8 0%,#ffffff 100%);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset, 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05) inset;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #222222;
    position: relative;
    height: 36px;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 42px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
        @include breakpoint($tablet){
            width:300px;
            }
        @include breakpoint($desktopsmall){
            width:400px;
            }
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       color: #999999;
    }

    &:-moz-placeholder {
       color: #999999;
    }

    &:focus{
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #2392F3 inset, 0 -1px 0 #2392F3 inset, 1px 0 0 #2392F3 inset, -1px 0 0 #2392F3 inset, 0 0 4px rgba(35,146,243,0.5);
        outline: none;
        background: url(../img/keyIcon.png) 12px 11px no-repeat, #FFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: `text-align:center;` on the input field would help. But why are there `.loginfield` `div`s around your input fields, there is no CSS for that included. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AENgL/).

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, you need to apply to all inputs, or specify class or id

```
input{
    text-align: center;
}

.text_center{
     text-align: center;
}
```

See this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/R85LS/